# Getting same value from list in dataframe column using Python

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have dataframe in which there 3 columns, Now, I added one more column and in which I am adding unique values using random function.
I created list variable and using for loop I am adding random string in that list variable
after that, I created another loop in which I am extracting value of list and adding it in column's value.
But, Same value is adding in each row everytime.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
lst = []
for i in range(20):
    randColumn = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                                              for i in range(20))
    lst.append(randColumn)
for j in lst:
   df['randColumn'] = j

print(df)

#Output.......
   A  B  C            randColumn
   0  1  2  3  WHI11NJBNI8BOTMA9RKA
   1  4  5  6  WHI11NJBNI8BOTMA9RKA
```

Could you please help me to fix this that Why each row has same value from list.

Comment: `for j in lst:\   df['randColumn'] = j` always sets every cell in the whole column to `j`, so in the end, all the cells will be equal to the last value of `j`. Is `lst` the same length as your dataframe?

Comment: I just corrected the indentation. And, yes, lst is the same length of my dataframe.

Comment: Is there any way to get the each value from list and add them to each row in dataframe ?

Comment: Ok, then instead of the `for j in lst` part you can just do `df['randColumn'] = lst`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine on python, but when i use this Databricks Notebook then
it says that
'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I tried with this code as well df.withColumn('NewColumn',lit(lst)) but no luck

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to work correctly with any type of column in df.

---

If I got your question clearly, you can use method zip of rdd to achieve your goals.

```py
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
    import pyspark.sql.types as t

    lst = []
    for i in range(2):
        rand_column = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(20))
        # Adding random strings as Row to list
        lst.append(Row(random=rand_column))

    # Making rdd from random strings array
    random_rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(lst)

    res = df.rdd.zip(random_rdd).map(lambda rows: Row(**(rows[0].asDict()), **(rows[1].asDict()))).toDF()
```

Comment: hi Artem,
i get this error when i used your code in databricks 'property' object has no attribute 'parallelize' and what is the significate of *rows[0],*rows[1] in Row?

Comment: @RamandeepSingh Could you show output of type(spark_session.sparkContext)?


*rows[0] means unpack values from Row as positional arguments, and **(rows[0].asDict()) means unpack values from Row as named arguments.

Comment: it is showing "Property" as output of type(SparkSession.sparkContext)

Comment: You need to call sparcContext from your instance of SparkSession.

Hm, stop. Do you use spark or it's a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I am using PySpark dataframe

Comment: I tried PySpark dataframe but I am getting same error.
'property' object has no attribute 'parallelize'

Comment: Do you have variables spark and sc in your notebook?

Comment: No, I don't have any variable spark and sc in my notebook, I just import the SparkSession module